# react-native-devtools version wrong when running yarn install

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg

In my package.json I have:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "react-devtools": "^4.14.0",
  ...
},
"resolutions": {
  "react-devtools-core": "4.14.0"
}
```

when i try to run `yarn` it shows something like this

[image]

```
warning Resolution field "react-devtools-core@4.14.0" is incompatible with requested version "react-devtools-core@4.25.0"
```

in the warning, I want to know where version `@4.25.0` is coming from

I even removed every reference of `react-devtools-core` and `react-devtools` from `yarn.lock`, remove the `node_modules` folder and run `yarn` again, but still the same.

and when the app runs this is what is shows in React Native Debugger

[image]

it says `Devtools 4.25.0-....`

So where is the `4.25.0` coming from?

I do know how to resolve the overall issue, but I just want to understand the reason for the above happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your react native debugger comes with dev tools 4.25.0. You just need to put the same version in your resolution and it should be fine.